# ScrollViewer XAML : MouseWheel Not Working

Tags: c#, xaml, scrollviewer, windows-store

I'm developing an application for a small business and I have a problem with the Horizontal Scroll Viewer.

Horizontal ScrollViewer appears on the screen but the mouse wheel doesn't work.

I Have this XAML Code:

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,130,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ManipulationMode="All">
       <Grid Width="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="250*" ></ColumnDefinition>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="250*"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="250*"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="250*"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="65*" />
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="Στοιχεία Πελάτη" FontSize="50"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Όνομα :" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Επώνυμο :" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Τηλέφωνο :" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Κινητό :" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Διεύθυνση :" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Πόλη :" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Χώρα :" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Email :" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Α.Φ.Μ :" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="ΔΟΥ:" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Περιγραφή:" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="30"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="30"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="30"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="30"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Height="30"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Height="30"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Height="30"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Height="30"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Height="30"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="4" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
           <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="9" Content="Αποθήκευση" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></Button>
      </Grid>
   </ScrollViewer>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post XAML, any code that might be relevant, and a description of *exactly* what's not working, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to making sure your scrollviewer is being presented at a fixed width, therefore enabling scrolling within the viewer itself (it currently looks like the viewer doesn't need to scroll to display the content), change the viewer declaration to the following.

```
 <ScrollViewer 
    Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}"
    ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="True" 
    Margin="0,130,0,0" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    ManipulationMode="All">
```

The style should be defined in StandardStyles.xaml, but if you aren't using that file, the definition is as follows.

```
<Style x:Key="HorizontalScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
</Style>
```

Comment: For me, the key part I was missing was setting VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled. I had it set to Auto, and in doing so, horizontal scrolling via the mouse wheel did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the grid width and then check. Usually, if grid width is large or 'auto' the content automatically scales to fit and hence scrollviewer doesn't work.